# Get maximum price from a group by in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, max, grouping

Im sorry if my title isnt very descriptive as i didnt know how to explain what i needed in sql code in a title.

Basically i have 2 tables, theres a `submissions` table which contains `invoicenumber` and `totalexvat`. (`totalexvat` is the `sum` of all the `part_exvats` in the livedata` table.

The `livedata` table contains `invoicenumber`, `part_code` and `part_price`

What i need to do is return all the data from the `submissions` table but also include **ONLY** the **most expensive** product in `livedata` which is the `part_code` and `part_price` joining the two tables together on `invoicenumber`

```
submissions
invoicenumber   totalexvat
1                     £123.00
2                     £354.00
3                     £453.00


livedata
invoicenumber       part_code        part_price
1                     prt12345         £100.00
1                     prt13643         £20.00
1                     prt63456         £3.00
2                     prt64232         £300.00
2                     prt28258         £54.00
3                     prt64232         £300.00
3                     prt67252         £153.00
```

I hope i have explained it well enough and hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is add a join condition and check that the price equals the max price for that item, using a subquery.

Something like this:

```
select * 
from submissions s
inner join livedata l 
    on s.invoicenumber = l.invoicenumber 
    and l.part_price = 
        (select MAX(part_price) 
        from livedata 
        where invoicenumber = l.invoicenumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you could use a subquery to accomplish this, but there are a couple of potential problems. The subquery would look something like this:

```
SELECT submissions.totalexvat
       ,livedata.part_code
       ,livedata.part_price
FROM submissions
INNER JOIN
(SELECT invoicenumber
        ,MAX(part_price)
FROM livedata
GROUP BY invoicenumber) ld_max
ON submissions.invoicenumber = ld_max.invoicenumber
INNER JOIN livedata
ON ld_max.invoicenumber = livedata.invoicenumber
    AND ld_max.part_price = livedata.part_price
```

In this example the "ld_max" subquery is identifying what the price for the most expensive part per invoice number.  Then you go back to the livedata table and rejoin to get what the part_code is that corresponds to the price.

The potential problem with this is if you have multiple parts that have the same price, and that price is the maximum, then you are going to get both of those parts returned by the final join.  If this is not the desired behaviour, (which it might be, it's not clear by the question), then you could avoid this by having a nested subquery and pulling only the top 1 result.  But then you're just kind of arbitrarily taking one of the parts and excluding the other, which seems like not a great idea.  It's also not a great idea because nested subqueries are by their very nature slow, so I'd watch out for those.

Answer (score 0):

You should use windowing functions - ie : `row_number()`

```
 select * 
 from 
 (
   select submissions.totalexvat,
          livedata.part_code,
          livedata.part_price,
          row_number() over (partition by submissions.invoicenumber order by part_price desc) rn
   from
       submissions
           inner join livedata on submissions.invoicenumber = livedata.invoicenumber
 ) r
 where rn = 1
```